# Run smarty foreach loop for more than the number of items in array

Tags: html, smarty

I have a nested array in smarty
outer array having 10 items (inner arrays)
inner array have different number of items in each of them.

I want to loop through them like this

```
    {foreach $group.plans as $plan}
    {if $plan@index eq 4}{break}{/if}
    <div class="wpct_comparison_table_col">
        <ul class="wpct_comparison_table_feature_values">
            {foreach $plan.description_section[$name@key] as $desc}
            {if $desc@index eq $group.rows}{break}{/if}
            <li>
                <span class="wpct_comp_feature_title_responsive">
                {if $desc@key eq ""}-{/if}{$desc@key}
                </span>
                {if $desc eq ""}-
                {elseif $desc|lower eq "yes"}<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                {elseif $desc|lower eq "no"}<i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                {else}{$desc}
                {/if}
            </li>
            {/foreach}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {/foreach}
```

The problem is, I want the inner li's to be equal to the number of highest number of items in any any inner array

For example:

```
$plan.description_section[0] has 10 items
$plan.description_section[1] has 12 items
$plan.description_section[2] has 15 items
```

Then I want to run inner loop for 15 times, generating empty li's as below

```
$plan.description_section[0] will create 5 empty li's
$plan.description_section[1] will create 3 empty li's
```

Comment: You could make use of smartys *[for](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.for.tpl)* loop

Comment: Hello @AlexG how I will get the values of inner loop? for example, $desc@key

Comment: `$foo` will contain the index of your current loop. `$plan.description_section[$name@key][$foo]` should work in theory. I haven't tried this myself though :)